# How to write sklearn.SimpleImputer in a function using a dataframe?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-analysis, imputation

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
df_titanic['age'] = imputer.fit_transform(df_titanic[['age']])
df_titanic['age']
```

I want to write this in a function to make it reusable. I tried several methods but all give an error.

```
def simple_imputer_func(data,strategy):
    simple_imputer = impute.SimpleImputer(strategy=strategy)
    X_num = simple_imputer.fit_transform(data)
    return X_num
X_num = np.array(simple_imputer_func(df_titanic['age'],'most_frequent'))
```

this one gives error as well

```
def imputer_func(data, imputer, strategy):
    simple_imputer = impute.imputer(strategy=strategy)
    X_num = simple_imputer.fit_transform(data)
    return X_num
X_num = np.array(simple_imputer_func(df_titanic['age'], SimpleImputer, 'most_frequent'))
```

Is there a way can I write them in a function and then give function the name of imputer which one to choose?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you pass `df_titanic['age']` as a parameter to your function, that is a `pandas.Series` object. You want instead a `pandas.DataFrame`.

In the original code, you were using `df_titanic[['age']]`, which supplies a list of a single column (age) to select from the Dataframe. This returns a `pandas.DataFrame` with just the age column, as opposed to the `pandas.Series` with the values from within the column.

Comment: that should be it. Thanks a lot for your help